# Get translations from .po or .mo file

Tags: php, gettext

How can I extract all translations from a .po or .mo file?
I need to create an array of all translations that are inside.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Zend Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) module from Zend Framework.

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate('gettext', '/path/to/english.mo', 'en');
$translate->addTranslation('/path/to/german.mo', 'de');

echo $translate->_("Example");

$translate->setLocale('de');

echo $translate->_("Example");
```

or you can use php [gettext](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/ref.gettext.php) module, but Zend is much more handy.

Answer (score 2):

msgunfmt is a unix tool that reads .mo files and produces a .po file.

Answer (score 1):

I used [po2csv](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/csv2po.html) to convert the po, then read the csv into php using the `fgetcsv()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small extraction AWK script in PhpWiki 1.2, called **translate.sh**. Use that (on Linux).
It greps all .po files and generates a .php array() script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PEAR File_Gettext](http://pear.php.net/package/File_Gettext/redirected). The code would then be:

```
$mocreator = new File_Gettext_MO();
$mocreator->load('/path/to/mo/file/file.mo');

foreach ($mocreator->strings as $key => $value) {
  echo "Key is $key \n";
  echo "Value is $value \n";
}
```