# Fetch all messages from current domain in PHP gettext

Tags: php, gettext

There is a [gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php)() function in PHP to lookup a message in the current domain.

Is there a way to fetch all messages from current domain?

Comment: It seems unlikely as that is not how this works. You poll for specific messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. The low-level libgettext API doesn't provide a means either.

You might use (and rewrite) the gettext Adapter from [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html) (or php-gettext or gettext.php) to read out a whole gettext message file however.

Comment: So basicly, to do that, you need to write parser for .mo files?

Comment: @umpirsky: Effectively yes. Or better a parser for the .po files if they are available (simpler text format).

Comment: It still does not have provide any kind of "fetch_all_messages" method, does it?

Comment: @mms27 Probably never will. The gettext API hasn't evolved since the 90s. Message catalogues are just key:value lookup files really. You might better go for a custom all-PHP implementation then.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gettext.php) says no.

Answer (score 0):

The current domain by definition contains infinite messages, so your question is not so useful.  The question "How to enumerate the messages within a particular message catalog?" may be more suitable.

[Get translations from .po or .mo file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920754/get-translations-from-po-or-mo-file)

This is possible on the command line, e.g.

```
$ msgcat <catalog-name>
...
#: conf/global_settings.py:44
msgid "Arabic"
msgstr "Árabe"

#: conf/global_settings.py:45
msgid "Bengali"
msgstr "Bengalês"
```