# How to make a small website multilingual?

Tags: php, xml, web

I have this really tiny (static) site, that is basically just my online business card and I want to have it in English and German. I detect the browser language and also let the user chose manually; so I have the right $lang variable ready.

My question is how are the multiple languages best implemented (or loaded)? Right now I do this with PHP switch statements but I feel this is not proper at all. My next guess is to use XMLs, one for every language, then load the right one but I wonder if there is a more clean, simple and proper way to do this; meaning easy to maintain and extend, easy to understand, compliant with standards and fast.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an array with all the texts, and place them in seperate files (one for German, one for English):

```
<? return array(
       'contact' => 'Kontakt'
);
```

Load that array and use it to display the text.

If you're using a CMS (content management system) there are other options.

Comment: +1. Using arrays like this make it much easier to fallback to a given language if a translation does not exist, using array_merge for example. See http://3v4l.org/dQb9t

Comment: Just to get this right... When I first load the page, I load the array of the corresponding language with an include. When I then want to insert the text I do array['contact'] or array['introduction']? What if I want to have HTML code inside the strings? Do I use CDATA?

Comment: In its simplest form, yep. HTML? CDATA would be irrelevant.

Comment: Indeed. If your included file starts with `return` you can use `$lang = include('de.php')`. Or as Anthony suggested (+1 for that): `$lang = array_merge(include('en.php'), include('de.php'));` if English is your fallback language.

Answer (score 0):

The standard PHP way is to use [gettext functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) and .po/.mo files as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809762/2905135)