# Why does Yii ignore my .po file?

Tags: php, yii, gettext, po

Since Yii can not create PO files without a special extension, I just created a .po file with [Poedit](http://poedit.net/). I want use [`CGettextMessageSource`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGettextMessageSource) and configured everything in `main.php`.

But Yii is just ignoring my settings in `main.php` and my .po file itself.

**main.php**

```
'language' => 'de_DE',
[...]    
'components' => array(
    'messages' => array(
        'class' => 'CGettextMessageSource',
        'useMoFile' => false,
        'catalog' => 'messages',
        'basePath' => 'protected/messages'
    ),
),
```

**my po file**

```
protected => messages => de_DE => messages.mo, messages.po
```

**content of my .po file**

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: myTest\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-04-28 17:18+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2014-04-29 09:16+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: de_DE\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.6.4\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: t\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: /..."
"trunk/fe/htdocs/protected\n"

#: /htdocs/protected/views/site/index.php:9
msgid "_TEST_"
msgstr "Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application."
```

Since I can not extend the `t`-function because of strict standards I wrote a wrapper in `yii.php` which I copied to `protected` and include it in `main.php`.

```
class Yii extends YiiBase
{
    public static function _($message, $category, $params = array())
    {
        return parent::t($category, $message, $params);
    }
}
```

And this is my index.php where I have a string that should be converted:

```
<?php echo Yii::_('_TEST_', 'messages');?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all **Yii did not ignore my .po file**.

## Problem:

Yii is just bugged.

If you want use .po files for translation it uses class [CGettextPoFile](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/i18n/gettext/CGettextPoFile.php):

```
public function load($file,$context)
{
    $pattern='/(msgctxt\s+"(.*?(?<!\\\\))")?\s+'
        .'msgid\s+((?:".*(?<!\\\\)"\s*)+)\s+'
        .'msgstr\s+((?:".*(?<!\\\\)"\s*)+)/';
    $matches=array();
    $n=preg_match_all($pattern,file_get_contents($file),$matches);

    $messages=array();
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
    {
        if($matches[2][$i]===$context)
        {
            $id=$this->decode($matches[3][$i]);
            $message=$this->decode($matches[4][$i]);
            $messages[$id]=$message;
        }
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

Like you can see - maybe not on first view, but later for sure, the pattern makes 'msgctxt' optional. But the problem is, that in the for loop it checks if exactly this 'msgctxt' from .po file matches with category that you pass to `t()`.

So if you do not have for every .po entry a 'msgctxt' it won't work. Further you can see that this class has a save function too - but there is no chance to use it (or I did not find any way to use it). Because if you use `yiic messages` it always generates a php file, whether you setup `CGettextMessage` in your console settings or not.

## Solution:

Since I do not want fix this load of code, I thought about just use php's gettext. Sideeffect is, that I can parse it much easier with tools like [Poedit](http://poedit.net/).

And best of all is - there is already a Yii extension that you can use very easy - [Yii-gettext](http://github.com/acerix/yii-gettext)!

Since I am really new to gettext() I was a little bit confused where to place and how to name my translation files. But on SO I have found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802093/how-to-run-or-load-po-mo-files-for-localization-in-php/8809762#8809762) where they explain it very good. (Beside the fact, that I had to edit this post as well. Because the author used `domain` messages which was a little bit confusing, because the hard coded path part of gettext folder is `LC_MESSAGES`. So I renamed `domain` messages to mycatalog.)

**Remember:**

```
bindtextdomain(<your namespace for your .mo/.po file>, <your directory>);

//put your files into: 
//<your directory>/<language i.e. en_EN>/LC_MESSAGES/<your namespace/domain>.mo/.po
//i.e.:
//  /htdocs/locale/en_EN/LC_MESSAGES/mycatalog.mo
//  /htdocs/locale/en_EN/LC_MESSAGES/mycatalog.po
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the context "msgctxt" in your po file.

```
[...]
msgctxt "messages"
msgid "_TEST_"
msgstr "Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application."

msgctxt "messages"
msgid "_TEST2_"
msgstr "Another translated text."
[...]
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But Yii does not generate those `msgctxt` entries.

Comment: Well, Yii does not generate any po files. But it generates PHP array files and an extension [pophpcommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pophpcommand/) does not generate `msgctxt` entries. Further it only works with one `catalog`. It seems that this whole PO `CGettextMessageSource` thing is bugged.

Answer (score 0):

As @chris--- said you miss [msgctxt](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_mono/gettext.html#index-msgctxt). Tell poedit to generate `msgctxt` from `Yii:t()` `category` param by setting appropriate header in your .po file:

```
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: t:1c,2\n"
```

This means, that first parameter will be used as `context` in gettext, and second -- as message string.

Also see my [wiki article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/773/gettext-and-poedit-howto/).