# Load .mo files in C

Tags: c, translation, gettext, po, mo

I've been working on a project, and I've finally decided to make translation files, so now I have translated .po files, but I don't know how to use it now on C, just that I have to make .mo files using those .po (no mattter with that).

I've been looking around but I've found answers which are for php (like this one: [How to run or load .po/.mo files for localization in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802093/how-to-run-or-load-po-mo-files-for-localization-in-php)) but nothing for C so if you could help me it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You don't load the files directly, that's done by gettext.

See [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html). It's long, but it's pretty good.